# BufferredWriter.write() to process works in Intellij, but not in jar

Tags: java, python, io, cryptocurrency, trezor

I'm trying to run the program [trezorctl](https://github.com/trezor/trezor-firmware/blob/master/python/docs/EXAMPLES.rst) to sign a [Qtum](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/q/qtum.asp) transaction built in Java alongside a [Trezor](https://trezor.io/) device, by creating a process through `ProcessBuilder` that runs the command `trezorctl sign-tx <name_of_file>.json`. After running it, you will often need to input your PIN before confirming the transaction.

I am inputting the PIN to the process using a `BufferedWriter(OutputStreamWriter(proc.getOutputStream()))` by calling `write(pin)`, then `newLine()`, then `flush()`. This works on Linux and on Mac when running the program through Intellij, but when I build the jar file and run that, it doesn't. `trezorctl` doesn't receive the input and my program hangs at the next `stdInput.next()`. On Windows this behaviour also occurs on Intellij.

Why would it work in one case and not the other, even within the same OS? When I run the command line application manually on Windows, it works on cmd, but not on Git bash, exhibiting similar behaviour. I don't know if this matters, but `trezorctl` masks the input so you can't see the PIN, would that affect this? I've also tried running my program with `sudo`, so I don't think it's a permission issue.

Comment: *I don't know if this matters, but trezorctl masks the input so you can't see the PIN, would that affect this?* Might do. btw, I don't know if I missed it, but I didn't see what the problem actually IS. Is there an option to enter the PIN as an argument? Yes, I know that would be a security risk but in you case it might be useful

Comment: You can't enter it as an argument, because every time it asks for it, a new PIN layout appears on your Trezor's screen and you have to input the numbers that would correspond to it on a standard PIN keyboard. i.e. if it shows

9 5 4

3 6 7

1 8 2

and if your PIN is 1234, you have to input 1349. For reference, the standard PIN keyboard would be 

 7 8 9
    4 5 6
    1 2 3

Comment: I think you misunderstand: if you can enter it as an argument, then it wouldn't need to ask for it. What i mean is akin to entering a password (as in MySql) with `-pSomePassword`

Comment: it's not possible to enter it as an argument, because the generated keypad layout is different each time, so you type a different "pin" each time. Here is an image of what it looks like on the command line
https://imgur.com/a/oG4GUnx

Comment: And then on the Trezor device screen it shows the unique keypad layout

Comment: Ah I see. I think you're going to have to look at the source to bypass that